# iOS 8 Tap on UITextView freezes the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uitextview

I have an old code, without ARC, without Autolayout and I am constructing the`UITableViewCell` programmatically. The`UITableViewCell` contains a`UITextView`. The cell is constructed properly but when I tap on the`UITextView` for editing the app freezes and after some time it exists (I think it's because it's taking a lot of CPU Time). This only happens with iOS 8, other versions it works fine.

I debugged and I do get`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification but the keyboard does not show up and I can't do anything after this.

Below is the code

```
// Register notification when the keyboard will be show
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    // Register notification when the keyboard will be hide
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(MIN_X,(LABEL_HEIGHT + VERTICAL_PADDING) + 2,TEXT_BOX_WIDTH,TEXT_BOX_HEIGHT);
    self.roundRectView = [[RoundRectView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    self.roundRectView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:roundRectView];

    inputTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    inputTextView.editable = YES;
    inputTextView.delegate = self;

    if(self.parameter.selectedValue == nil || [self.parameter.selectedValue length] == 0){
        inputTextView.text = self.parameter.label;
    }

    else{
        inputTextView.text = self.parameter.selectedValue;
    }

    inputTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    inputTextView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    inputTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15.0];
    inputTextView.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    inputTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    inputTextView.bounces = NO;
    inputTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [self.contentView addSubview:inputTextView];
```

Below is the`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` handler :-

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note{

if([self.inputTextView isFirstResponder]) {
// Get the keyboard size
CGRect keyboardBounds;
[[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

// Detect orientation
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
CGRect frame = self.parentTableView.frame;

// Start animation
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

// Reduce size of the Table view 
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    frame.size.height -= keyboardBounds.size.height-100;
else 
    frame.size.height -= keyboardBounds.size.width-100;

// Apply new size of table view
self.parentTableView.frame = frame;

// Scroll the table view to see the TextField just above the keyboard
if (self.inputTextView)
{
    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.parentTableView convertRect:self.inputTextView.bounds fromView:self.inputTextView];
    [self.parentTableView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:NO];
}

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}}
```

Below is the crash report. My app name is "My App"

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.myapp.app failed to exit in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 8.070 (user 8.070, system 0.000), 66% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 5.689, 47% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   QuartzCore                      0x27e013ca x_hash_table_lookup + 62
1   QuartzCore                      0x27e10c60 CAMediaTimingCopyRenderTiming + 120
2   QuartzCore                      0x27e0fd4a CA::Layer::add_animation(CAAnimation*, __CFString const*) + 650
3   QuartzCore                      0x27e0f876 -[CALayer addAnimation:forKey:] + 478
4   UIKit                           0x28673c4c __67-[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:]_block_invoke + 376
5   UIKit                           0x28673a98 -[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:] + 544
6   QuartzCore                      0x27e02788 CA::Layer::end_change(CA::Transaction*, unsigned int, objc_object*) + 92
7   QuartzCore                      0x27e03322 CA::Layer::set_bounds(CA::Rect const&, bool) + 522
8   QuartzCore                      0x27e03046 -[CALayer setBounds:] + 106
9   QuartzCore                      0x27e0407a -[CALayer setFrame:] + 538
10  UIKit                           0x283dcfde -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 250
11  UIKit                           0x283f7408 -[UIView(Geometry) _applyAutoresizingMaskWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 804
12  UIKit                           0x283f70d2 -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 254
13  CoreFoundation                  0x24e6506e __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 86
14  CoreFoundation                  0x24e64f68 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 200
15  UIKit                           0x283e7bea -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 114
16  UIKit                           0x283dd0f2 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 526
17  UIKit                           0x28469320 -[UILayoutContainerView setFrame:] + 56
18  UIKit                           0x283f7408 -[UIView(Geometry) _applyAutoresizingMaskWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 804
19  UIKit                           0x283f70d2 -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 254
20  CoreFoundation                  0x24e6506e __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 86
21  CoreFoundation                  0x24e64f68 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 200
22  UIKit                           0x283e7bea -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 114
23  UIKit                           0x28429b40 -[UIView(Geometry) setBounds:] + 476
24  UIKit                           0x288b7ad8 -[UIDropShadowView setBounds:] + 124
25  UIKit                           0x287cdf84 -[_UIFormSheetPresentationController containerViewWillLayoutSubviews] + 272
26  UIKit                           0x283e0154 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 440
27  QuartzCore                      0x27e0bf60 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 132
28  QuartzCore                      0x27e0794c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 356
29  UIKit                           0x283f28e6 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 134
30  UIKit                           0x28413d22 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 474
31  UIKit                           0x28413b3e +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:animations:] + 62
32  UIKit                           0x287cdb44 -[_UIFormSheetPresentationController _changeLayoutModeToAvoidKeyboard:] + 220
33  CoreFoundation                  0x24ef6f12 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 10
34  CoreFoundation                  0x24e51e48 _CFXNotificationPost + 1796
35  Foundation                      0x25b86e5c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
36  UIKit                           0x28a44b94 -[UIInputWindowController postStartNotifications:withInfo:] + 412
37  UIKit                           0x28a45fb4 __77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke579 + 396
38  UIKit                           0x28413d22 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 474
39  UIKit                           0x284d579e +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:start:completion:] + 62
40  UIKit                           0x284a093a -[UIInputViewAnimationStyle launchAnimation:afterStarted:completion:forHost:fromCurrentPosition:] + 166
41  UIKit                           0x28a45d18 -[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:] + 828
42  UIKit                           0x28a49584 -[UIInputWindowController setPlacement:starting:completion:] + 44
43  UIKit                           0x28a4913a -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 610
44  UIKit                           0x28a457aa -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 38
45  UIKit                           0x28498102 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1010
46  UIKit                           0x2845b7f0 -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 404
47  UIKit                           0x2845bab6 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 102
48  UIKit                           0x2857ab6a -[UITextView becomeFirstResponder] + 70
49  UIKit                           0x2857aa6a -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 170
50  UIKit                           0x2857a36a -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 1994
51  UIKit                           0x285601aa _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 290
52  UIKit                           0x2840ec98 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 664
53  UIKit                           0x28823a8c ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke661 + 44
54  UIKit                           0x283d8512 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 214
55  UIKit                           0x283d648a _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2946
56  UIKit                           0x2840d088 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 780
57  UIKit                           0x2840c958 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 516
58  UIKit                           0x283e30e0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 192
59  My App              0x0023e95a 0x28000 + 2189658
60  UIKit                           0x28656b9e _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 13870
61  UIKit                           0x283e1b22 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1290
62  CoreFoundation                  0x24f04fd4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
63  CoreFoundation                  0x24f043e6 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 +     218
64  CoreFoundation                  0x24f02a64 __CFRunLoopRun + 764
65  CoreFoundation                  0x24e4fb2c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
66  CoreFoundation                  0x24e4f93e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
67  GraphicsServices                0x2c1d504c GSEventRunModal + 132
68  UIKit                           0x28441f1c UIApplicationMain + 1436
69  My App              0x0002e56e 0x28000 + 25966
70  My App              0x0002e4f4 0x28000 + 25844
```

Comment: Are you getting any memory warning before crashing?

Comment: The report I have attached is actually not the Crash report but the report after the app shutdowns around 10mins after I click the TextView for editing. I think this is because it goes into some loop and it utilises a lot of CPU time and memory and hence the OS is killing the app.

Comment: Did you get the solution? Its difficult to figure out without code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my solution if anyone faces same issue.

The TextView was in an view controller which was presented modally using UIModalPresentationFormSheet presentation style. After I changed to UIModalPresentationPageSheet it worked fine. This means the Form sheet caused some problem while popping up the keyboard.